# Is there a function the produces pseudorandom permutations of the first $N$ positive integers?

Tags: functions, permutations, random

Context: I found a function that simulates the results from throwing an $N$-sided die. That is, a function $f(N,n)$ composed of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and the floor or ceiling function such that the numbers $f(N,1), f(N,2), f(N,3), ...$ are a [pseudorandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) sequence of integers ranging from $1$ to $N$:

> $f(N,n)=\lceil\frac{N}{\pi}\arccos{(\cos{(10^n)})}\rceil$

Here is a plot of $f(6,n)$ against $n$:

[image]

Now I am wondering, is there a function that produces **pseudorandom permutations of the first $N$ positive integers**? That is, a function $g(N,n)$ composed of elementary functions and the floor or ceiling function such that, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$
, the numbers $g(N,kN+1), g(N,kN+2), g(N,kN+3), ..., g(N,kN+N)$ are a pseudorandom permutation of the first $N$ positive integers.

I do not know how to make the function's outputs not repeat within each interval of $N$ outputs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: And Fisher-Yates is roughly equivalent to picking a number randomly from 0 to n!-1 and converting it to a permutation via the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).